# How to print an Isosceles triangle in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, codeblocks

I'm trying to create an isosceles triangle with '*' symbol from user's input in C++.

For example, with user's input of 5, I must get:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I'm getting only:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

My c++ code:

```
void askData(int &n){
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>n;
}

void print(int A){
    for(int j=1;j<=A;j++)
    cout<<"*";
    cout<<endl;
}

void createIsoscTriangle(int n){

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    print(i);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    askData(n);
    createIsoscTriangle(n);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the correct form of the isosceles triangle?

Comment: Take this one step at a time. Can you think of how to create a loop that will result in the sequence `1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1`?

Comment: You'll have to count down, too.  There are lots of related questions for various shapes — triangles, pyramids, and others.

Comment: So, run the same loop (minus the first iterator) in reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern of stars is `1`, `2`, `3`, `...`, `n`, `n - 1`, `n - 2`, `...`, 1. as Brian mentioned in the comments. So, Numbers of stars for each line would be `n - abs(n - i)`, where abs is the absolute value of `n - i`, and that should work for any `n` not just `5`.

I've modified your createIsoscTriangle function to be the following:

```
void createIsoscTriangle(int n) {

    for(int i = 1; i <= n * 2 - 1; i++)
        print(n - abs(n - i)); 
}
```

Let's try it for `n = 5`. It would print the figure you mentioned.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

You only print sequence `1 2 3 4 5`. You also need a loop which would count down.

```c++
void createIsoscTriangle(int n) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      print(i);
    for(int i = n-1; i >= 1; i--)
      print(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpful.